Add new column for product table in new orders from back end (ADMIN)
I want to add a column in this table. It is the product table to create a new order from the magento admin panel.

This is to be able to know the qty per package while creating orders ourselves.
Does anyone know how to do this with or without code?
Thanks!

You need to overwrite the following grid class and add a column

vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Search/Grid.php

